# Need best way to whitelist the params in this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I need to convert this code in my ConfirmationsController to work in Rails 4. I'm having difficulty with the requirements for Strong Parameters. The code I'm using is directly from the [Devise page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Email-only-sign-up)

I'm pretty sure that anything I am calling with params needs to be whitelisted but I can't quite figure out how to do that in this case. What is the best way to accomplish this.

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

def show
  self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token]) if params[:confirmation_token].present?
  super if resource.nil? or resource.confirmed?
end

def confirm
  self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(params[resource_name][:confirmation_token]) if params[resource_name][:confirmation_token].present?
  if resource.update_attributes(params[resource_name].except(:confirmation_token).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)) && resource.password_match?
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[resource_name][:confirmation_token])
    set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
    sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  else
    render action: "show"
  end
end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(confirmation_token) if confirmation_token.present?
    super if resource.nil? or resource.confirmed?
  end

  def confirm
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(confirmation_token) if confirmation_token.present?
    if resource.update_attributes(resource_params) && resource.password_match?
      self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(confirmation_token)
      set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
      sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
    else
      render action: "show"
    end
  end

  private

  def resource_params
    # pry
    # debugger 
    params.require(resource_name).permit :password, :password_confirmation
  end

  def confirmation_token
    params.require(resource_name).permit :confirmation_token
  end
end
```

More info: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters
If you continue having trouble I'd recommend stuffing a debugger or pry in the middle and manipulating the params with `permit` | `require` until you have what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks, however when I change my code to the above, I end up with an error: param not found: user

better errors highlights this line: params.require(resource_name).permit :confirmation_token

Comment: Devise stuff goes beyond my comprehension and -possibly- the scope of this question; on the other hand, if the params you are looking for are optional, then use `permit` instead of `require`.

Comment: You are right the devise stuff is beyond the scope of the question. I'll submit a new question. Thanks for the help